# Constructor injection in application where dependencies might not be able to be initialized

Tags: constructor, inversion-of-control

My application is able to start without a database connection, how do I handle this with IoC and constructor injection?

Example:

```
public class ApplicationShellPresenter(IRepository repository, IView view)
{

}
```

When IRepository in this case will be constructed an exception will be thrown due to underlaying DAL cannot find config/file, wrong username/password etc. etc.

With this in mind I came to the conclusion that I cannot inject the repository in the constructor OR inject anything that eventually along the line have IRepository as dependency.

I need to start without IRepository dependency and when the user have made the correct database settings, register the IRepository in the container. But then I have already left the composition root.

**Edit:**

My problem was not really a IoC/Constructor injection - problem but rather a design flaw in our underlaying DAL.

Our DAL is constructing itself upon creation. And thats why that design didn't work because I couldn't construct a IRepository dependency without constructing our DAL-engine.

My simple solution was to wrap our DAL so it didn't construct itself upon creation.

Answer (score 1):

Take this a stage further. If I understand you correctly we have:

```
Application Starts

User specifies some database settings

Repository initialises, passwords etc are checked

Application now uses repository
```

My immediate thought is, hmmm, wonder whether we can also get

```
User decides "I don't like that repository"

User specified new database settings

New repository is initialised

Application closes previous repository, and starts working with new one.
```

Now it may be that this is slightly more flexible than you had planned, but it leads me to thing that you have effectively two applications, with a transient relationship between them. There's the "shell", which is independent of the repository, that's the bit that starts up without a repository. Then there's the extra piece that works only when it's got a repository, and I think is seems to be pluggable, at least in concept.

Hence I don't think your shell is so much  being "Injected" as responding to interesting events such as:

```
Here is a repository, if you already have one please close it

Shut down, please close down your repository, and then yourself.
```

If you have a Event Interface I think you get what you need. The arrival of an Event is in effect an Injection.

Answer (score 1):

See [how I would do it](http://kozmic.pl/archive/2010/06/22/how-i-use-inversion-of-control-containers-ndash-pulling-from.aspx).

Comment: Nice, I also came up with the factory aproach, but one thing is still bothering me. In my application I have lots of implementations requiring IRepository. How do I solve that with a factory? Do I have to wrapp every implementation that needs a IRepository with a class that takes a dependency on the IRepositoryFactory instead? Seems kind a awkward.

Comment: what seems awkward is the fact that the repository needs configured and active connection to function. What ORM are you using? It feels very flawed.

Comment: I have figured it out now, our DAL we currently use was initalized when constructed and thats was our real problem, I just wrapped it into another class that wasn't initalized in the constructor and then I was able to inject IRepository in the application shell constructor without any problems.

So this wasn't really a IoC problem when you look at it. But thanks anyway for your blog-post.